# how do you add attributes to script tag in jade e.g. async defer

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I needed to add async and defer attributes according to the docs for adding a google plus one button. How do I do this in jade?

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because I think you've already tried script(src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js', async, defer), but I went on jade-lang.com/demo and I tried , the online compiler saw ok, function template(locals) {
    var buf = [];
    var jade_mixins = {};
    var jade_interp;
    buf.push('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/site.css">    <title>Hello</title>  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script></head><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>');
    return buf.join("");
} and seems ok

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
script(async, defer, src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js')
```

Comment: I have this currently working: script(async defer src="https://maps.goog...")

Comment: Getting "TypeError: code.replace is not a function" when I include script(async ...) or script(async, ...). Note one has a comma and one doesn't. Have to write it as script(async="true")